# How to create DataFrame from the an array in Scala?

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, azure-data-factory

I have a use case where I need to create a DataFrame from an array.

I've created a DataFrame that reads a CSV then I am using a map to process/transform it further.

```scala
    var mapTransform = df1.collect.map( 
      line => {
      // line.split(",") logic for fields separation
      //transformation logic here for various fields

      (field1+","+field2+","+field3);  
      }
    )
```

From this, I am getting an `array(Array[String])` which is transformed result.

I want to further convert it DataFrames with separate columns so that later it can be used to write to DB or file, however, I am facing an issue. Is it possible to do it? Any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does your job:
`spark.sparkContext.parallelize(mapTransform.toSeq)`
But note that you must avoid methods that produce non-rdd, as they load all the contents of the array to the one node and that's ineffective in the general case.

Also, there's a convention turn `var`s to `val`s as much as possible.